# style.marginRight doesn't work the same way style.marginLeft does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

First function pushes content to the left yet the second one doesn't push it to the right

```
function openNavLeft() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenavLeft").style.width = "100vw";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "100vw";
}

function openNavRight() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenavRight").style.width = "100vw";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "100vw";
}
```

So my question is what should I do different or why is this broken?

Comment: It depends on the HTML and how the CSS of the parent has been configured. In other words, we can't really give you an definitive answer without seeing more of your code.

Comment: [link](https://wompdoo.github.io/webstate/) here is the project, at the bottom where there is looking for a job and such

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a margin to the left of an element (left say a div to be safe).

If there is no margin the div will go as close to the left as it can because it was made in a left to right language.

If you add a margin to the left it will push the 'div' to the right because the space to the left if filled.

If you put a margin on the right you're just filling up space after the 'div' so it doesn't have to move anywhere.

If you have something occupying space before the 'div' a right margin won't move it out the way.

I've added a little diagram to hopefully help with my explanation.

```
----------------------
|       WEBPAGE      |
|                    |
|[div]               |
|                    |
|[   Left Margin    ]|[div] 
|                    |
|[div][ Right Margin |    ]
|                    |
|[img][div][   Right | Margin ]
|                    |
----------------------
```

Comment: Okay, but if the div is the body tag, this means it should still push the content? [link](https://wompdoo.github.io/webstate) You can check it out here